# Convert Java Date into XML Date Format (and vice versa)

Tags: java, xml, string, date

Is there a nice and easy way to convert a Java Date into XML date string format and vice versa?

Cheers,

Andez

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'XML date string format'? Can you post examples?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Original answer

I am guessing here that by "XML Date Format" you mean something like "2010-11-04T19:14Z". It is actually [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

You can convert it using SimpleDateFormat, as others suggested, FastDateFormat or using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) which was I believe especially created for [this purpose](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html).

### Edit: code samples and more

As **earnshae** stated in a comment, this answer could be improved with examples.

First, we have to make clear that the original answer is pretty outdated. It's because Java 8 introduced the classes to manipulate date and time - `java.time` package should be of interest. If you are lucky enough to be using Java 8, you should use one of them. However, these things are surprisingly difficult to get right.

#### LocalDate(Time) that isn't

Consider this example:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-03-23T18:21");
System.out.println(dateTime); // 2016-03-23T18:21
```

At first it may seem that what we're using here is a local (to the user date and time). However, if you dare to ask, you'll get different result:

```
System.out.println(dateTime.getChronology()); // ISO
```

This actually, the ISO time. I believe it should read 'UTC' but nonetheless this has no notion of local time zone. So we should consider it universal.
Please notice, that there is no "Z" at the end of the string we are parsing. Should you add anything apart of date and time, you'll be greeted with `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`. So it seems that this class is of no use if we want to parse ISO8601 string.

#### ZonedDateTime to the rescue

Fortunately, there is a class that allows for parsing ISO8601 strings - it's a [java.time.ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-03-23T18:21+01:00");
System.out.println(zonedDateTime); // 2016-03-23T18:21+01:00
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeZulu = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-03-23T18:21Z");
System.out.println(zonedDateTimeZulu); // 2016-03-23T18:21Z
```

The only problem here is, you actually need to use time zone designation. Trying to parse raw date time (i.e. "2016-03-23T18:21") will result in already mentioned `RuntimeException`. Depending on the situation you'd have to choose between `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`.
Of course you can easily convert between those two, so it should not be a problem:

```
System.out.println(zonedDateTimeZulu.toLocalDateTime()); // 2016-03-23T18:21
// Zone conversion
ZonedDateTime cetDateTime = zonedDateTimeZulu.toLocalDateTime()
   .atZone(ZoneId.of("CET"));
System.out.println(cetDateTime); // 2016-03-23T18:21+01:00[CET]
```

I recommend using this classes nowadays. However, if your job description includes archeology (meaning you are not lucky enough to be working with more than 2 year old Java 8...), you may need to use something else.

#### The joy of SimpleDateFormat

I am not a very big fan of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, but sometimes you just have no other choice. Problem is, it is not thread-safe and it will throw a checked `Exception` (namely `ParseException`) in your face if it dislikes something. Therefore the code snippet is rather ugly:

```
private Object lock = new Object();
// ...
try {
    synchronized (lock) {
        // Either "2016-03-23T18:21+01:00" or "2016-03-23T18:21Z"
        // will be correctly parsed (mind the different meaning though)
        Date date = dateFormat.parse("2016-03-23T18:21Z");
        System.out.println(date); // Wed Mar 23 19:21:00 CET 2016
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    LOG.error("Date time parsing exception", e);
}
```

#### FastDateFormat

`FastDateFormat` is synchronized, therefore you can at least get rid of the synchronized block. However, it is an external dependency. But since it's the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and it is thoroughly used, I guess it is acceptable. It is actually very similar in usage to `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
FastDateFormat fastDateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX");
try {
    Date fastDate = fastDateFormat.parse("2016-03-23T18:21+01:00");
    System.out.println(fastDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    LOG.error("Date time parsing exception", e);
}
```

#### JodaTime

With Joda-Time you may think that following works:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();        
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-03-23T20:48+01:00", parser);
System.out.println(dateTime); // 2016-03-23T20:48:00.000
```

Unfortunately, no matter what you put at last position (Z, +03:00, ...) the result will be the same. Clearly, it isn't working.
Well, you really should be parsing it directly:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
DateTime dateTime = parser.parseDateTime("2016-03-23T21:12:23+04:00");
System.out.println(dateTime); // 2016-03-23T18:12:23.000+01:00
```

Now it will be OK. Please note, that unlike one of other answers, I used `dateTimeParser()` and ***not*** `dateTime()`. I noticed subtle, but important difference in behavior between them (Joda-Time 2.9.2). But, I leave it to the reader to test it and confirm.

Comment: +1 for Joda Time reference which is a much better solution than the SimpleDateFormat which is fraught with hazard

Comment: yes this is what I am looking for.  Cheers Andez.  @Gary Rowe - why is it fraught upon?  I have been using it for well over the last year now and absolutely hate everything with Java dates and times.  Our company has it's own wrapper round a GregorianCalendar which always calls TimeZone.setDefault("...") everytime it is instantiated.  I never wrote it, just had to work with it or around it :-(

Comment: This answer would be better with code attached to it.

Answer (score 21):

As already suggested use SimpleDateFormat.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);
Date d = sdf.parse(date);
```

My guess is that the format/pattern that your looking for is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`
Also have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp

Answer (score 9):

Using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Formatters) you would do the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime(); // ISO8601 (XML) Date/time
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime("2000-01-01T12:00:00+100"); // +1hr time zone
System.out.println(fmt.print(dt)); // Prints in ISO8601 format
```

Thread safe, immutable and simple.

Answer (score 8):

The Perfect method, use XMLGregorianCalendar:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(v);
DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
return dateTime.toString();
```

Answer (score 7):

Just by using SimpleDateFormat in java we can do this...

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date date = sdf.parse("2011-12-31T15:05:50+1000");
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend to use the java built in class [javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html). It can handle conversion to and from most of the xml simple types. It is a little bit cumbersome for dates that you have to go through a `Calendar` object but on the other hand it handles all variants of zone information that can occur in a xml `datetime` field.

From xml:

```
    Calendar c = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2015-10-21T13:25");
    Date d = c.getTime();
```

To xml:

```
    Date yourDate = new Date()
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(yourDate);
    String xmlDateTime = DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c);
```

**EDIT**

*The DatatypeConverter class is no longer publicly visible in Java 9 and above since it belongs to the javax.xml.bind package. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) for more information and possible solutions. The solution proposed by **loic vaugeois** to use XmlGregorianCalendar is much better in this case.*

Answer (score 3):

You can parse and format dates to and from any format using [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

To comply with ISO8601, the timezone must be in the format +HH:MM or - HH:MM

With Simpledateformat you must use XXX instead of Z (see NovelGuy answer)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what format you need, the generic response is: you're going to want DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat. There is a nice tutorial on both [here](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/).