# SQLite and inserting the current date in UTC format

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

How do I use an SQL statement on an sqllite database to insert the current date in UTC.  I found the `NOW` function but what format is that in?  This will be on mobile devices so everyone will have a different locale, however, I need a standard time format because the device will compare the dates with my server.

Also, is there a way to automatically update a 'modified' field when the data in the row is changed like you can in MySQL?

Comment: The application is written in Java on Android

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SELECT DATETIME('now')` returns the current UTC datetime. See [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). You can use DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with column declaration.

> Format 11, the string 'now', is
>   converted into the current date and
>   time as obtained from the xCurrentTime
>   method of the sqlite3_vfs object in
>   use. Universal Coordinated Time (UTC)
>   is used

For the 'modified' field you can use a trigger.

Comment: how do I get it to print like this YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099862/convert-java-date-into-xml-date-format-and-vice-versa/4100363#4100363

Comment: @jax  You can get your expected format using this format `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'` . Example `SELECT  strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',DATETIME('now', 'utc'))`

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify what you use to develop your application on. I prefer using `QDate::toJulianDay` and `QDate::fromJulianDay` in Qt to store dates in an SQLite database as an integer if I only need to store the date.