# How to show a dialog box randomly in application

Tags: android, dialog

i was wondering if someone could tell me how to show an alert dialog box that has a "rate this app" button, i want the dialog to show, for example every week or even just once.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: To be honest, any app which did this to me would get a rating of 0 and then be un-installed.

Comment: whoever voted down can go to hell

Comment: you can use: https://github.com/codemybrainsout/smart-app-rate/ library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store somewhere (maybe in the database) the date and time of the last time the user saw the alert in the app and check if enough time has passed since then.

If the last time that the alert was shown was more than three days ago, you show the alert, if it is less than three days, you don't.

Comment: You can get the current time like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266263/sqlite-and-inserting-the-current-date-in-utc-format and add it to sql and get the data like they explain here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html