# How to identify date format?

Tags: java, date, calendar

1) If I print out a calendar object I get:
`java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1567535353679,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=36,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=246,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=18,MINUTE=29,SECOND=13,MILLISECOND=679,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]`

2) If I print out a Date object I get:

`Tue Sep 03 18:29:13 GMT 2019`

3) However I am examining the XML generated and I observe this format:

`2014-02-28T08:00:00.000Z`

Which format am I seeing in the XML ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Java Date into XML Date Format (and vice versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099862/convert-java-date-into-xml-date-format-and-vice-versa)

Comment: What do you mean by "examining the XML generated"? What tool or class?

Comment: I recommend that you use neither `Date` nor `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `OffsetDateTime` and `Instant` have `toString` methods that can give you the format you observed in XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Date-time objects have no “format”

> How to identify date format?

Date-time objects do not have a “format”. Each class defines its own mechanism for internally storing the date-time value. That mechanism is generally none of our business. The API of the class, the promises made by that class, are all that matters.

You may be conflating the text generated by a date-time object with the date-time object itself. Date-time classes can parse text as part of  their instantiation. And date-time classes can generate text to represent their value. But the text and the object are separate and distinct.

## Avoid `Calendar`

> If I print out a calendar object I get:

The `Calendar::toString` method is just a data-dump of many of its internal fields. Meant only for debugging obviously, not useful otherwise.

The [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html) class and its commonly-used subclass [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) are both now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). They were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes as of the adoption of JSR 310. Never use them. `GregorianCalendar` was specifically replaced by `ZonedDateTime`.

## Avoid `Date`

> If I print out a Date object I get:

The [`Date::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#toString()) method lies. That method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating text. A `java.util.Date` actually represents a moment in UTC, not the time zone seen in the result of `toString`. This anti-feature is one of many reasons to never use `Date`.

The `java.util.Date` class was replaced by `java.time.Instant`, representing a moment in UTC as well but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds versus milliseconds.

## ISO 8601

> However I am examining the XML generated and I observe this format:
>
> 2014-02-28T08:00:00.000Z

The format of that text is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. This standard is wisely designed to represent a variety of date-time values textually for data-exchange. This standard supplants earlier poorly-defined date-time text formats, such as seen in the early email protocols.

The *java.time* classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

## Current moment in UTC

To capture the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Generate text representing that value in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

> 2020-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z

Parse such a string.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2020-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z" );
```

## Time zone

See that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate a string in a format that wisely extends the ISO 8601 standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/AzkfRi).

> instant.toString(): 2020-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2020-01-23T07:34:56.123456-05:00[America/Montreal]

## Date-time types in Java

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: That was a lot of text to answer the simple question "Which format am I seeing in the XML ?", which is the only question posed, and then you didn't even get it right. The date format used in XML is defined by the XML Schema data types specification ([XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/)), and the [`dateTime`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) data type is "closely related to" / "inspired by" ISO 8601, so not actually ISO 8601.

Comment: @Andreas Actually that "XML format" is only 1/4th of the Question, but thanks for the feedback. As for the context of that string in XML, the Question makes no mention of XML Schema being involved, and did not even explain where that string came from. Indeed, I posted a Comment on the Question asking for that explanation.

Comment: Actually, there is only only question, in the last line. The rest are statements of facts, not questions. If OP meant all of them to be questions, then OP should learn [how to ask a better question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Andreas I must read the Question differently than you.

Answer (score 2):

> Which format am I seeing in the XML ?

The XML format is inspired by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), as specified by the [XML schema documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime).

> *3.2.7.1 Lexical representation*
>
> The [·lexical space·](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-lexical-space) of **dateTime** consists of finite-length sequences of characters of the form: `'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?`